# App does not refreshes the options in the list

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have made an app which takes words and definitions from two text files(one with word and other with definitions). A random number is used to generate a word to display and then shuffles and arranges 5 definitions along with the right one to display options. The app runs perfectly but when clicking any option it doesn't refresh the options with new ones for the next word.

```
ListView list;

ArrayAdapter<String> adap;
ArrayList<String> word=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> dfn=new ArrayList<>();
List<String> dfn2=new ArrayList<>();

String que="",ans="";
int counter=0;

private void random(){
    Random num = new Random();
    int nw = num.nextInt(word.size());

    que = word.get(nw);
    ans = dfn2.get(nw);
    dfn = dfn2;
    dfn.remove(ans);
    Collections.shuffle(dfn);
    dfn = dfn.subList(0,4);
    dfn.add(ans);
    Collections.shuffle(dfn);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.li);


    adap = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            dfn
    );
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
    t.setText(que);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.word2));
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.def2));
    while(sc.hasNextLine()&&sc2.hasNextLine()){
        String a = sc.nextLine();
        String b = sc2.nextLine();
        word.add(a);
        dfn.add(b);
        dfn2.add(b);


    }
    sc.close();
    sc2.close();
    random();
    run();
}



public void run(){


    list.setAdapter(adap);
    list.setOnItemClickListener((adapterView, view,i,l)->{//lambda expression
                if(dfn.get(i).equals(ans)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Correct!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    counter++;

                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);
                t2.setText("Score : "+counter);
                notifyDataChanged();

            }

    );

}

public void notifyDataChanged() {

    random();
    adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


}
```

I want the options to be replaced with new ones after every click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do create a new adapter with every click but you don't set the new adapter to the list.

Instead of creating a new adapter each time, you should just update the values. Just in that case you also have to call notifyDataSetChanged (what you already do but you don't have to)

```
if (adapt == null) {
    adap = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            dfn
    );
} else {
   adapt.updateItems(dfn);
   adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void notifyDataChanged() {
    random();
}
```